# Simple C++ exception error (MEX)

Tags: c++, exception, mex

I am working on adapting some C++ code from Windows to Linux to compile as mex in Matlab.  The program is designed to connect a data glove via a virtual serial port.  I've never worked much at all with C++ before, so the solution this issue could very well be quite simple.  In a larger file, I am getting issues caused by the following try/catch:

```
try
{
    // You can tell which com port to use by checking windows settings under hardware
    glove = new CyberGlove(portName, (int) *baudRate);  // baudrate 115200                                                

    /* Return CyberGlove object */
    mxArray* result = (mxArray*) mxMalloc(sizeof(CyberGlove));
    *reinterpret_cast<CyberGlove*>(result) = *glove;
    plhs[0] = result;
}
catch(std::runtime_error err)
{
    std::cout << "Error: " << err.what() << std::endl;
}      

delete glove;
```

When I try to compile it in Matlab, I get the following errors:

```
InitCyberGlove.cpp: In function ‘void mexFunction(int, mxArray**, int, const mxArray**)’:
InitCyberGlove.cpp:43:11: error: expected type-specifier
InitCyberGlove.cpp:43:30: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘err’
InitCyberGlove.cpp:43:30: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘err’
InitCyberGlove.cpp:43:30: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘err’
InitCyberGlove.cpp:43:30: error: ‘err’ was not declared in this scope
InitCyberGlove.cpp:43:33: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
```

I don't think it's specifically related to the CyberGlove stuff so much as my general lack of knowledge of C++ and how exceptions work.

Comment: Consider putting glove in a smart pointer - if you get an exception it will never get deleted

Comment: Btw, it's a good idea to catch exceptions in C++ by const reference. eg, `catch( const std::runtime_error &err)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `#include <stdexcept>` where `std::runtime_error` is declared.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm not sure why that wasn't already included, but problem solved.  Now I just have to figure out why it fails to link...